# Better way to code returning the result of a true/false call

Tags: javascript, language-agnostic, function, conditional-statements

Many times, I'm writing a function which will return `true` on success and `false` on error/failure, and essentially wrapping another function which does the same.

An example (basically language-independent, but I'll write in ECMAScript for familiarity):

```
function SendEmail(to, from, subject, body) {
 var eml = new EmailObj();
 eml.To = to;
 eml.From = from;
 eml.Subject = subject;
 eml.Body = body;
 return eml.Send(); // This will return true/false
}
```

But, sometimes, I want to do something else depending on the result of the interior function (say log specific information):

```
function SendEmail(to, from, subject, body) {
 var eml = new EmailObj();
 eml.To = to;
 eml.From = from;
 eml.Subject = subject;
 eml.Body = body;
 if(!eml.Send()) {
  Log("Error in send: " + eml.Response);
  return false;
 }

 return true;
}
```

But, I never feel like I've written good code when I do something like that.

Would you write this differently?  Am I being paranoid?  Or do you think this pattern in and of itself leads to this dilemma and I should look to see if I can change the higher-level approach(es)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure exactly why you are worried about it, but another option is this:

```
var ret = eml.Send();
if (!ret)
  Log("Error in send: " + eml.Response);
return ret;
```

Answer (score 3):

If the language supports it (JavaScript does) you can also consider [**Exception Handling**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Statements#Exception_Handling_Statements).